# How do i find my WiFi password when i am already connected but it doesnt show

Tags: wifi, password

I am trying to find my WiFi password from my iPad and I am connected to it.

Is there anyway I can find out when I am connected to it?

Comment: See the similar discussion at http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/is-there-any-way-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-on-the-iphone?rq=1  Unless you have jailbroken the ipad, you cannot access the passwords.

Answer (score 2):

At present, there is no way to find out, but I am offering this as an answer anyway despite it being covered by the linked answer:

1) If you have a Mac connected to the same network, you can find the stored password in it's Keychain

2) If the router is an Apple Airport based device, you may be able to log straight into it via Airport Utility (available on Mac and iOS) to see the password at source

3) If you are patient, you can wait for iOS7 to be released, which will include Keychain Syncing, allowing the stored password on your iPad to be synced elsewhere, giving you potential to then read it in your Keychain as per point 1.

Comment: Why didn't you post this as answer to the linked question instead?