# WiFi IPhone 5C Password

Tags: iphone

How can I find out what my wifi password is for my iphone?  I entered what I thought was password but it will not connect.  I can't find it written down anywhere to be sure.

Comment: Are you using your iPhone as a personal hotspot? Or are you trying to connect your phone to a WiFi network?

Comment: There are several questions covering the basics of this. Feel free to edit your question if they duplicates, related questions and linked questions to the right don't apply to your situation.

Comment: http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/105329/recover-forgotten-wifi-password

Answer (score 1):

The iPhone simply stores the wifi password that you entered for the network. What you see are dots hiding the password. There is no way to get the iPhone to show you the password, which is a very valuable security feature.

Fortunately, the wifi password is not something the iPhone controls. That is controlled by the Wifi router. If you forgot the password, simply log into the router admin screen, and check the password there or reset it.