# How can I retrieve a saved WiFi password from iOS / iPadOS on secure hardware?

Tags: ios, password, keychain, jailbreak, ipados

I have some wireless networks that I joined on my iOS device and I now want to retrieve the passwords from the device.

These are stored in the keychain presumably so I’d like (by hook or crook if necessary) to get into the iOS / iPadOS keychain and obtain saved passwords or secrets.

I'm primarily interested in old hotspot passwords, but being able to list other items in the iOS keychain would be generally useful. If I need to use a computer, that's fine, but I would also be interested in ways to accomplish this from iOS itself if that is possible.

Is the keychain exportable forensically or natively on modern iOS devices with a physical Secure Enclave?

Comment: Also http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/is-there-any-way-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-on-the-iphone is very similar, although the answers are not iOS 7 specific or address secure enclave and forensic options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a jailbreak application called [WiFi Passwords](http://cydiaupdates.net/pkg/com.malcolmhall.wifipasswords). It's free by [Malcolm Hall](http://www.malcolmhall.com/) in the BigBoss Cydia repository. It allows you to view all of the passwords for the networks that you've joined (including usernames for WPA2 Enterprise networks).

Comment: Funny story about Malcolm Hall, actually. I was at JailbreakCon 2012 in San Francisco, and my friend and I were talking about a jailbreak tweak called [Stealth Cam](http://cydiaupdates.net/pkg/com.malcolmhall.stealthcam), and the guy in front of us turned around and said, "I made that tweak." It was Malcolm Hall. After that we talked a lot, hung out at the conference, exchanged tweak ideas, and had lunch together.

Answer (score 19):

One trivial solution is to enable keychain sync for iOS 7 and have the keychain contents sent to iCloud.

Then, on a Mac, enable keychain syncing in the iCloud preference pane in system preferences and use Keychain Utility to inspect the iCloud keychain.

[image: Keychain item contents - showing WiFi password]

Once above step is completed. Open Keychains on Mac and look for iCloud on the right panel. You should then see all the SSID you have ever saved on your various devices and computers synced through iCloud.

Comment: I like this answer more because I won't have to jailbreak my phone. I'm gonna try this at home.