# Retrive saved wifi password from iPhone 6

Tags: wifi, password

Is there a way to find out the password of a saved wifi network from an iPhone 6 running 12.2?

This sending/sharing the password doesn't seem to work on this version.

I have no access to the router. (not hacking, just community difficulties in college dorm, and it's an ubee anyway. those devices have individual admin passwords printed on their bottoms)

thank you

Comment: I don't see a way to do this in iOS, but if you'd ever logged in to the wifi network on a Mac, the password is easily available through the Keychain app in macOS.

Comment: Take a look at bmike's answer in this: https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/114923/how-can-i-retrieve-a-saved-wifi-password-from-ios-7-and-newer

Comment: Good detail and use case - I’ve linked to one more recent question and one for much older hardware and os. +1 for asking.