# Is it possible to access a list of wifi networks my iPhone has used?

Tags: iphone, ios

I understand I may have to jailbreak my phone to access this, but is there a way to view a list of networks my iPhone has remembered and get info on the date they were last accessed?

I know there are some apps that allow you to view all the stored passwords for previously accessed networks but I'm also interested in seeing the date they were last accessed.

Thanks in advance of any help you can give.

Comment: I need this for an account WITHOUT iCloud Keychain. It may help me locate a place where I was kidnapped and robbed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### 1. If you have iCloud Keychain enabled :

> **Are my existing saved passwords, Wi-Fi networks, and Internet accounts included in iCloud Keychain?**
>   Yes. When you turn on iCloud Keychain, any previously-saved website usernames and passwords, Wi-Fi networks, and Internet accounts are automatically included in iCloud Keychain.

From : 
http://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204085

- You can access to Keychain by the Keychain Access.app (located in /Applications/Utilities/).

### 2. Otherwise you can use 1Password.

### 3. Finally, you have this post :

[Is there any way to view saved wifi passwords on the iPhone?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/54551/is-there-any-way-to-view-saved-wifi-passwords-on-the-iphone)

> Unfortunately, on the iPhone it is not possible to access this information. The passwords are kept on your phone in a safe place that is not accessible through any regular means on the phone. This is done for your protection, if you were to lose your iPhone and someone picked it up, the passwords that are stored on it would be up for grabs. This would lead to a lot of security problems.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, but there's a catch to the keychain; see below.

The following is all for Yosemite (I had version 10.10.3).

## To see wifi networks you've connected to from your iOS devices:

- On your OSX device (eg your Mac), make sure you are logged in to iCloud (via System Preferences).
- Open the Keychain Access app desribed above.
- On the left, in the Keychains box, click "iCloud".
- In the main display, click on "Kind" to sort all entries by kind.
- All the wifi networks will now be listed together with the kind "AirPort network password".

## To view a wifi password:

- Double click one of the displayed entries (or right-click it and select Show Info).
- Click the checkbox next to "Show Password".
- Enter your iCloud password.

## The catch

You have to enter the iCloud password you had when you first connected to that network. If you have since changed your iCloud password, your current iCloud password won't work. There won't even be an error message: after you click OK, no password will be displayed, that's all.

This is obviously a bad problem: who can remember their old iCloud passwords? It's sad that Apple hasn't fixed this yet.

Personally, I get around the problem by using 1Password (https://agilebits.com) whenever I change my iCloud password. 1Password keeps a log of all my previously created passwords with their creation dates; so, I look at the Keychain Access entry's "Date Modified", and then in 1Password I choose the last iCloud password I created before that date.